# Why does this .htaccess loop?

Tags: htaccess

if I try to redirect any page on a certain domain to one specific page (SEO does not matter, here), this ends in a loop - but I don't get why:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/page.html [R=302,L]
```

I am able to use the same page in a positive second condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http_://_domain.com/other-page.html [R=302,L]
```

Please, enlighten me. TIA

Complete *.htaccess* file added ("myedit"s and "Custom redirects" are mine):

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
# myedit: added default charset

##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

# myedit: added (though probably not necessary, here)
Options -Indexes

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
# myedit: moved up from below "Custom redirects"; may not be needed
#RewriteBase /

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.

# Kill www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Should be faster, but nogo - strange, IfModule does work
#<If "req('Host') == 'www.domain2.com'">
# Redirect / http://domain2.com/
#</If>
# More general rule, If we _wanted_ www - does "http_host - www" exist?
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Get the right page for domain2.com
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/page\.html$ /other-page.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.de/page.html [R=302,L]

# Redirect /+ to google+
#Redirect 301 /+ https://plus.google.com/u/0/id-here/about

# Shortlink for google maps
#RewriteRule ^$ http://goo.gl/maps/short-url-here [R,L]

# ErrorDocument - nogo, needs joomla extension?
#ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

#
## End - Custom redirects

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In the first example you have `!` on the 2nd line, while on the 2nd example you have no `!` i.e `!^/page\.html$ [NC]` vs `^/page\.html$ [NC]`

Comment: The first block of code you have posted does _not_ result in a loop!? There would seem to be something else that is causing this?

Comment: @bybe Right, that was intentional. I only want to get the first example working - the second one was just for testing purposes using the same URI.

Comment: @w3d Thanks, but what else could cause this? It's a joomla installation hosted at mittwald.de.  All my custom rules are as follows:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/page.html [R=302,L]

Comment: @kamome Have you `RewriteBase` directive inside your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @freedev I do, "RewriteBase /" (sorry, had to eliminate some stuff, because of text limit). But commenting RewriteBase doesn't change the symptom.

Comment: @kamome if it is not too big, please post the entire `.htaccess` file

Comment: @freedev complete .htaccess added in main post

Comment: Is the .htaccess into the document root?

Comment: It is, yes. It's the standard Joomla htaccess with just a few additions. Both domains have the same document root.

Comment: @kamome: Moot point, but you say you do have `RewriteBase`, however, this is not included in the "complete" script above? Also, you've removed the comments (as stated) - whilst this might not be significant, the comments might actually help, particularly if the comments say one thing and your code appears to do another?

Comment: @kamome As far as I see removing the `RewriteBase` directive should fix the problem you pointed out. But on the other hand it should introduce new unexpected behaviors. All rewrite rules should change accordingly with the `RewriteBase` setting.

Comment: @kamome IMHO, maybe for sake of clarity or privacy, you removed few lines and renamed domains and/or paths from `.htaccess` file. 
This action introduced few changes that hidden important informations, useful to solve the problem, and wasted the time of all people trying to help you. Next time better show the whole context as is as much as possible.

Comment: @w3d As it didn't seem to change anything, I left RewriteBase commented, now. Well, I wanted to spare you all the boring details, but you are right - added everything now, all the cruft in there ;)

Comment: @freedev Thank you for your perseverance! I did add everything now. But I really thought it better not to bother everyone with all the "unnecessary" stuff, sorry. Also, how could RewriteBase change this, if I set it to "/" - this .htaccess is in the DocumentRoot.

Comment: @kamome I have updated my answer to explain how `RewriteBase /` could change this

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your rewrite I see a little typo, the dot in `page\.html` should not be escaped, since this is not a regular expression, but only the destination URL. This is the correct `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/page.html [R=302,L]
```

This could be the reason why `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.html$ [NC]` doesn't match.

On the other hand, the easiest way I can suggest to solve this problem is enable `RewriteLog` with a sufficient high level and check it.

**Update**

<s>Please pay attention if you've `RewriteBase URL-path` defined.
`RewriteBase` directive will remove the defined `URL-path` from `%{REQUEST_URI}`.</s>

For example assume your request path is `/page.html` and into `.htaccess` file you have `RewriteBase /`, then `%{REQUEST_URI}` will contain only `page.html`. 
To be clear, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.html$ [NC]` cannot match because the leading slash is missing.

Removed. Thanks to @w3d for the comment. I understood that `RewriteBase` affects only the `RewriteRule pattern` part.

**Update 2**

I have created a dummy virtual host with rewritelog enabled to test the given `.htaccess` file. Everything works well if the `page.html` file exist. But if the file not exist:

```
[... omissis ...]
(3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'page.html'
(4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.com' pattern='^domain2\\.com$' [NC] => matched
(4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='/page.html' pattern='!^/page\\.html$' [NC] => not-matched
[... omissis ...]
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/page.html' pattern='!-f' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/page.html' pattern='!-d' => matched
rewrite 'page.html' -> 'index.php'
trying to replace prefix /var/www/ with /
(5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/index.php -> index.php
(4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
(1) [perdir /var/www/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
(4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain2.com' pattern='^domain2\\.com$' [NC] => matched
(4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='/index.php' pattern='!^/page\\.html$' [NC] => matched
(2) [perdir /var/www/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'http://domain.de/page.html'
(2) [perdir /var/www/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://domain.de/page.html
(1) [perdir /var/www/] escaping http://domain.de/page.html for redirect
(1) [perdir /var/www/] redirect to http://domain.de/page.html [REDIRECT/302]
```

It seems that `page.html` will be replaced by `index.php` before the internal redirect. Then the internal redirect execute again the `.htaccess` file.
During this new execution the request URL is changed into `index.php` and the redirect will be triggered as expected.
This should explain why you have a redirect loop.

Comment: Whilst the escaped dot in the RewriteRule substitution is unnecessary and should be avoided for readability, it is not actually invalid and makes no difference to the running of the script.

Comment: @freedev, thanks, but that was actually a typo in the post - I don't have that Backslash in the destination, anymore ;) And thanks for the pointer to RewriteLog - but that only results in an error 500 (shared hosting, perhaps not allowed?).

Comment: @kamome `RewriteLog` is available only in the following contexts: server config, virtual host; i.e. you cannot use it inside `.htaccess` file

Comment: @freedev: You seem to be mistaken, `RewriteBase` does not affect the value of the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable - this _always_ contains the full path component of the requested URI. The value of `RewriteBase` effects _relative_ path substitutions in the `RewriteRule`.